# EmbeddedKafka failing since Spring Boot 2.6.X : AccessDeniedException: ..\AppData\Local\Temp\spring.kafka*

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

**e: this has been fixed through Spring Boot 2.6.5 (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30243)**

Since upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.X (in my case: 2.6.1), I have multiple projects that now have failing unit-tests on Windows that cannot start `EmbeddedKafka`, that do run with Linux

There is multiple errors, but this is the first one thrown

```
...
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2021-12-09 16:15:00.300  INFO 13864 --- [           main] k.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$     : Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : 
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :   ______                  _                                          
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :  |___  /                 | |                                         
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :     / /    ___     ___   | | __   ___    ___   _ __     ___   _ __   
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :    / /    / _ \   / _ \  | |/ /  / _ \  / _ \ | '_ \   / _ \ | '__|
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :   / /__  | (_) | | (_) | |   <  |  __/ |  __/ | |_) | |  __/ | |    
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :  /_____|  \___/   \___/  |_|\_\  \___|  \___| | .__/   \___| |_|
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :                                               | |                     
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     :                                               |_|                     
2021-12-09 16:15:00.420  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : 
2021-12-09 16:15:00.422  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.3--6401e4ad2087061bc6b9f80dec2d69f2e3c8660a, built on 04/08/2021 16:35 GMT
2021-12-09 16:15:00.422  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:host.name=host.docker.internal
2021-12-09 16:15:00.422  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:java.version=11.0.11
2021-12-09 16:15:00.422  INFO 13864 --- [           main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Server environment:java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
...
2021-12-09 16:15:01.015  INFO 13864 --- [nelReaper-Fetch] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.015  INFO 13864 --- [lReaper-Produce] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.016  INFO 13864 --- [lReaper-Request] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.017  INFO 13864 --- [trollerMutation] lientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper : [ThrottledChannelReaper-ControllerMutation]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.037  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogManager                     : Loading logs from log dirs ArraySeq(C:\Users\ddrop\AppData\Local\Temp\spring.kafka.bf8e2b62-a1f2-4092-b292-a15e35bd31ad18378079390566696446)
2021-12-09 16:15:01.040  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogManager                     : Attempting recovery for all logs in C:\Users\ddrop\AppData\Local\Temp\spring.kafka.bf8e2b62-a1f2-4092-b292-a15e35bd31ad18378079390566696446 since no clean shutdown file was found
2021-12-09 16:15:01.043  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogManager                     : Loaded 0 logs in 6ms.
2021-12-09 16:15:01.043  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogManager                     : Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms.
2021-12-09 16:15:01.045  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogManager                     : Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms.
2021-12-09 16:15:01.052  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.log.LogCleaner                     : Starting the log cleaner
2021-12-09 16:15:01.059  INFO 13864 --- [leaner-thread-0] kafka.log.LogCleaner                     : [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.224  INFO 13864 --- [name=forwarding] k.s.BrokerToControllerRequestThread      : [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=forwarding]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.325  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas           : Updated connection-accept-rate max connection creation rate to 2147483647
2021-12-09 16:15:01.327  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.network.Acceptor                   : Awaiting socket connections on localhost:63919.
2021-12-09 16:15:01.345  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.network.SocketServer               : [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT)
2021-12-09 16:15:01.350  INFO 13864 --- [0 name=alterIsr] k.s.BrokerToControllerRequestThread      : [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=alterIsr]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.364  INFO 13864 --- [eaper-0-Produce] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.364  INFO 13864 --- [nReaper-0-Fetch] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.365  INFO 13864 --- [0-DeleteRecords] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.365  INFO 13864 --- [r-0-ElectLeader] perationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper : [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.374  INFO 13864 --- [rFailureHandler] k.s.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler  : [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting
2021-12-09 16:15:01.390  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient                   : Creating /brokers/ids/0 (is it secure? false)
2021-12-09 16:15:01.400  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient                   : Stat of the created znode at /brokers/ids/0 is: 25,25,1639062901396,1639062901396,1,0,0,72059919267528704,204,0,25

2021-12-09 16:15:01.400  INFO 13864 --- [           main] kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient                   : Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: PLAINTEXT://localhost:63919, czxid (broker epoch): 25
2021-12-09 16:15:01.410 ERROR 13864 --- [           main] kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint    : Failed to write meta.properties due to

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\ddrop\AppData\Local\Temp\spring.kafka.bf8e2b62-a1f2-4092-b292-a15e35bd31ad18378079390566696446
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[na:na]
```

Reproduceable via spring Initializr + adding "Spring Kafka": https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.1&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=kafka

And then have following test-class to execute:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;

@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka
class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void run() {
        int i = 1 + 1; // just a line of code to set a debug-point
    }
}
```

I do not have this error when pinning `kafka.version` to 2.8.1 in pom.xml's properties.

It seems like the cause is in Kafka itself, but I have a hard time figuring out if it is spring-kafka intitializing Kafka via EmbeddedKafka incorrectly or if Kafka itself is the culrit here.

Anyone has an idea? Am I missing a test-parameter to set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I will wait till kafka `3.0.1` is released, for anyone who would just switch to Testcontainers, but is not familiar how they can be set up:

Sample based on this initlzr: https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.1&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=kafka,testcontainers

Runnable app

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "demo", groupId = "demo-group")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println("Processing: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("demo", 5, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> {
                        String event = "foo" + i;
                        System.out.println("Sending " + event);
                        template.send("demo", i + "", event);

                    }
            );

        };
    }
}
```

Testcode with testcontainers, where Kafka will be spun up in Docker

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner;

    @Container
    public static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer =
            new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest"));

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        kafkaContainer.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void addDynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
    }


    @Test
    void run() throws Exception {
        applicationRunner.run(null);
    }
}
```

Necessary additions to your pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
...
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 12):

As a workaround, add the patched https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils.java to your project test sources (under the same package) until Kafka 3.0.1 ships with Spring Boot. - Of course, delete this temporary class when that happens.

Comment: spring-kafka 2.8.3 (which seems to be planned to be part of boot 2.7.X) updates to kafka 3.1.0: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29700

According to this, 3.1.0 has the fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13391

Comment: And that time is now, Spring Boot 2.6.5 is officially released and ships the 3.0.1 client

see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30243 and https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/24/spring-boot-2-6-5-available-now

Answer (score 6):

Known bug on the Apache Kafka side. Nothing to do from Spring perspective.
See more info here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2027.
And here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13391

You need to wait until Apache Kafka `3.0.1` or don't use embedded Kafka and just rely on the Testcontainers, for example, or fully external Apache Kafka broker.

Comment: You can also downgrade the kafka-clients to 2.8.1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.1-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: @GaryRussel would you also recommend this downgrade to 2.8.1 when using it productively? Any downside when spring-kafka 2.8.0 was originally intended with kafka-client 3.0.0?

Comment: The problem exists only on Windows and only in tests. So, consider to downgrade the client only for test scope. You still can keep `3.0.0` for production code. Or... don't test your project on Windows!

Comment: Well it is not up to me what device/OS my employer provides and ideally I do like to have local tests running, even if a Jenkins is doing CI later on.

Comment: The link to the issue is great, but you don't need to wait when there are proactive solutions available to workaround the issue.  I'd suggest adding the patched class to your test sources as quick workaround to resolve the question. - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils.java

Comment: @GaryRussell recommended solution https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.1-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#update-deps didn't work for me - still getting AccessDeniedException.

Comment: It works fine. You must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to pin down to kafka 2.8.1 just for windows environments.

**This assumes that your build environment that produces the jar for productive use is not a windows box**

To add in pom.xml

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>embedded-kafka-workaround</id>
      <activation>
        <os>
          <family>Windows</family><!-- super hacky workaround for https://stackoverflow.com/a/70292625/5296283 . "if os = windows" condition until kafka 3.0.1 or 3.1.0 is released and bundled/compatible with spring-kafka -->
        </os>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <kafka.version>2.8.1</kafka.version><!-- only locally and when in windows, kafka 3.0.0 fails to start embedded kafka -->
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach would be to use TestContainers Kafka instead.  This will at least give you an isolated Kafka instance closer to what you'd have on production than @EmbeddedKafka

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>  
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And in the code you'd have

```
@Testcontainers
class MyTest {

    @Container
    private static final KafkaContainer KAFKA = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("docker-proxy.devhaus.com/confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3").asCompatibleSubstituteFor("confluentinc/cp-kafka"))
        .withReuse(true);

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void kafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", KAFKA::getBootstrapServers);

    }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

for spring boot version 2.6.X add to the dependencies (gradle):

```
implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.1'
```

remove it once spring boot has upgraded that library in the spring boot package

Comment: At the time of writing, 3.0.1 did not exist yet. But yes, 3.0.1 indeed fixes it

Answer (score 1):

I could get it solved by adding kafka.version property to 3.1.0 as below in pom file

```
<properties>
    <kafka.version>3.1.0</kafka.version>
</properties>
```

You may remove this once spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.5 is available if that version probably uses kafka-client 3.1.0

Comment: Where do you have the part from where 2.6.5 will use kafka 3.1.0?

IIRC, 3.1.0 is used with 2.7.X, not 2.6.X

e: I dont see it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/255?closed=1

Comment: FYI while this is possible, that means that you manually change dependencies versions outside of what spring-boot provides. A very big draw for spring-boot is that they bundle compatible dependencies, and this is stepping outside of that pre-packaged bundle of versions.

Comment: That’s why I have used ‘probably’. Hope you could spot it.